# Do I need to update Dark Souls 3 manually? Xbox One

Tags: dark-souls-3

I'm seeing on the menu screen:

`App Version: 1.04
 Regulation version: 1.06`

Does this mean my game is out of date by 2 versions? (.05 and .06)? If so, how am I able to get the current version with all of the patches?

I'm also having a very hard time being summoned or summoning other players. I'll try to summon at least 30 players and instantly get a  "Could not summon" message before I try to connect with someone. Is this because my game is outdated?

Comment: I have the same versions on PC, your game seems up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your game is not out-of-date -- the "App" version refers to the client-side software in general, and the "Regulation" version refers to the regulations for multiplayer interactions. These two things are versioned separately, so they will often have different version numbers.

As for your summoning issue, the "Unable to Summon" message usually happens when you attempt to summon a player after they have already been summoned. If you're in one of the beginning areas, it's more likely to happen as there are more people asking for help. Try to look for and activate summon signs the moment they show up, so you have a better chance of calling "dibs" on that phantom.